# Smalltalk, using 'value' on BlockClosure

Tags: smalltalk, extend

I am trying to create a method for the existing BlockClosure class. This is a method we wrote on the board in class, but it is not behaving exactly as I'd want it to. This is the code:

```
BlockClosure extend[
   times: count[
      count = 0
      ifTrue:
      [^self value.]
      ifFalse:
      [self value. self times: count - 1.].
   ]
].
```

I tried testing it out by inputting this into the gst interpreter:

```
st> x:= 5
5 
st> y := [x-1] times: 4.
a BlockClosure
```

But I want y to equal 1 in this case. Why is y's value becoming "a BlockClosure"?

EDIT: The correct times method.

```
BlockClosure extend[
   times: count[
      count = 0
      ifFalse:
      [self value. ^self times: count - 1.].
   ]
].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're missing the `^` in the `ifFalse:` branch of the conditional statement, which is preventing the return value from propagating back from the recursive call:

```
ifFalse:
[self value. ^self times: count - 1]
```

Secondly, this will actually set `y` to `4` instead, because you're computing `x - 1` with the same `x` value each time. What you probably mean to do is reassign back to `x` each time:

```
y := [x := x - 1] times: 4
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out it still returns "a BlockClosure", but that is the value of y. If I check the x value though, it has changed.

Comment: It returns a BlockClosure because your fixed "times:" method does not have an explicit return, so it implicitly returns self.